# Type Mismatch on ListView (v6) - Excel (VBA)

Tags: excel, listview, type-mismatch, vba

Why this code throws a 'Type Mismatch' error

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim lvw As ListView

    Set lvw = Me.ListView1
End Sub
```

While this not (Changed `ListView` with `Object`):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim lvw As Object

    Set lvw = Me.ListView1
End Sub
```

I am using ListView control version 6

Comment: In the first snippet, comment out the assignment and add `Debug.Print typename(Me.ListView1)`. What does it say?

Comment: Its says "ListView2" in the immediate window, so that's the type. I changed it to that and it worked. Thanks, this `typename` is new to me. Appreciate your help.